# Using Prim's Algorithm With Priority Queue?

Tags: python, algorithm, priority-queue, prims-algorithm

I am working on solving a graph using Prim's Algorithm and a Priority Queue. I have been given a class that contains code to handle edges and the graph itself. I also need to use a priority queue to find the minimum spanning tree.

How would you guys go about solving a problem like this? Would you get all the edges for each node, put it into the priority queue and then go from there?

Comment: Can you please show the class and some sample inputs?

Answer (score 0):

For Prims algorithm, my priority queue has `pairs (weight, vertex)`, ordered by weight.
Here is the pseudo code. Note that you just have to add the edge to priority queue for a vertex if it is better than all the edges that you have encountered for that edge.

```
key[v] = Infinity for all vertex v
vis[v] = false for all vertex v
Q.Push(0, 1) // weight 0, and 1 is a valid vertex
while (Q is not empty) :
  curV = first element of Q
  curW = second element of Q
  Q.pop
  if (vis[curV]) continue
  add curV to spanning tree
  for u in adjacency list of curV :
    if (not vis[u] and key[u] > weight(u, v)):
      Q.push(u, weight(u,v)
      key[u] = weight(u,v)
```